# Programs for electronic simulation

Tags: simulation

What software is used for this simulation?

[image]

Comment: your tags seem to be completely unrelated to the question you're asking. Have you tried using a search engine on the specific string at the bottom of the schematic?

Comment: If you're using someone else's pictures, be sure to include the links to where the images originally reside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LTspice from Analog Devices, formerly Linear Technologies.

Link:
https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html#